# How to use GridViewComboBoxColumn and allow the user to edit?

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview, wpfdatagrid

I need to present a WPF `GridView` where one column is a `Combobox`, The user can select one value from the list or enter a new value so I set the `IsComboBoxEditable` to `true` but the problem is that if the user types a value that is not in the `ItemsSource` the Text is blank when the `Combobox` looses the focus.

> Note : I don't want, when a new value is typed , this value to be
>   added to the `ItemsSource`. I only need to save it's `string` value in row
>   that bounded to it.

I also need  DropDownOpened event, to populate it's ItemsSource.

Here is my code:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Description">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <telerik:RadComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Descriptions}" Text="{Binding Description1,Mode=TwoWay}" DropDownOpened="descriptionRadComboBox_DropDownOpened"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

`Description1` is `string` property, and `Descriptions` is List of `string` that populate in runtime.(When `DropDownOpened` Event occurred)

Comment: Show relevant V and VM code snippet

Comment: I need a Editable ComboBoxColumn in WPF DataGrid.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've added my code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Like you mentioned, your goal is, simply, to "Editable ComboBox".
(And, of course, you don't want to add new Item to `ItemsSource`)

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn UniqueName="description1"  Header="Description">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description1}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <telerik:RadComboBox Name="SLStandardDescriptionsRadComboBox" IsEditable="True" 
                                                         ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SLStandardDescriptions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                                                        DisplayMemberPath="SLStandardDescriptionTitle" DropDownOpened="Description_DropDownOpened">
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>

</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Codebehinde :

```
private void RadGridView_CellEditEnded(object sender, GridViewCellEditEndedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cell.Column.UniqueName == "description1")
    {
        RadComboBox combo = e.Cell.ChildrenOfType<RadComboBox>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (combo != null)
        {
            List<Description> comboItems = combo.ItemsSource as List<Description>;

            string textEntered = e.Cell.ChildrenOfType<RadComboBox>().First().Text;

            bool result = comboItems.Contains(comboItems.Where(x => x.DescriptionTitle == textEntered).FirstOrDefault());
            if (!result)
            {
                comboItems.Add(new Description { DescriptionTitle = textEntered });
                combo.SelectedItem = new Description { DescriptionTitle = textEntered };
            }
            if (_viewModel.AccDocumentItem != null)
            {
                if (e.Cell.Column.UniqueName == "description1")
                    _viewModel.AccDocumentItem.Description1 = textEntered;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for .net DataGrid control:

```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Title}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ComboItem.ID}"  DisplayMemberPath="ComboTitle"  SelectedValuePath="ID">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ComboItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>                        
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ComboItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                        <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>                    
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Surely you can do this using Telerik DataGrid control as well.

And here is my ViewModel:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;  

            ComboItems = new ObservableCollection<ComboItem>()
            {
                new ComboItem(){ID=1,ComboTitle="ComboItem1"},
                new ComboItem(){ID=2,ComboTitle="ComboItem2"},
                new ComboItem(){ID=3,ComboTitle="ComboItem3"}
            };    
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
            {
                new Item(){ID=1,Title="Item1",ComboItem=ComboItems[0]},
                new Item(){ID=2,Title="Item2",ComboItem=ComboItems[1]},
                new Item(){ID=3,Title="Item3",ComboItem=ComboItems[2]}
            };                
        }    
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ComboItem> ComboItems { get; set; }               
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public ComboItem ComboItem { get; set; }
    }

    public class ComboItem
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ComboTitle { get; set; }
    }
```